# VScode golang debug error __debug_bin: Permission Denied

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, redhat, vscode-debugger

I am using a container [https://hub.docker.com/r/redhat/ubi9-init](https://redhat/ubi9-init) with SSH as a Golang development environment. When I have to debug a unit test I am receiving a permission error:

[image]
[image]

I've done some searches and found tips to add `*__ debug_bin` on `.gitignore` and check the Selinux permissions. Selinux is not present in this image. The `/Home` directory permissions in the container is 776 and I am logged in SSH as a root user. What else can I try?

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the same error here. My issue was that I inadvertently changed the package name of the main.go file from main to something else.

I'm not sure if it's your case, but hope it helps.